Is there a way to calculate this integral?
So I've been having fun with contour integrals, and what I found is that you can represent $\displaystyle\smash{\int_{a}^{b} \!\!f(x)\,dx}$ as:
$$
-\frac{b-a}{2} i \int_{0}^{\pi} \!f\biggl(\frac{b+a}{2}+\frac{b-a}{2}e^{i\theta}\!\biggr)\,e^{i\theta} \, d\theta 
$$
if you choose a contour containing no poles such as a semi-circle with boundary going from $a$ to $b$.
Then I tried it with the integral $\displaystyle\smash{\int_0^1 x^x\,dx}$ and came up with
$$
-\frac{i}{2} \int_{0}^{\pi} \biggl( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^{i\theta} \biggr)^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} e^{i\theta}} e^{i\theta} \, d\theta. 
$$
However now I'm wondering if there is a way to calculate the second integral. Is it even possible to calculate the second integral?

If your method works, it will get this. But we need to be careful: $z^z=\exp(z\ln z)$ has infinitely many branches.

What @J.G. said.  You will have to choose your contour to surround a region where $z^z$has an analytic branch.
